# Question about Newton's Shell Theorem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, symmetry

[image]

This drawing shows the [Newton's Shell Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) about the situation that the point mass $M_1$ is outside the spherical shell $M_{\text{shell}}$.

My teacher showed that the differential element of the potential energy of that system is equal to

$$dU=-G\frac{M_1dM}{r_1}$$

$dM: \text{The mass of the ring that has infinitesimal thickness $d\theta$.}$

My question is, why is the denominator of that expression equals to $r_1$?

I think, it should equal to the distance between point mass and center of the ring. So, $$dU=-G\frac{M_1dM}{r-R\cos(\theta)}.$$ Am I false?

Comment: the distance to the masses dM is the distance r1 to the ring , not  to the center. and the denominator is the distance between M1 and dM

Comment: I think I don't understand you. Could you explain more clearly, please?

Comment: $$r_1=\sqrt {R^2 \sin^2(\theta)+[r-R \cos(\theta)]^2}$$ This tidies up nicely...

Comment: M1 is attracted by each differential part of the ring, and it is at a distance of $r_1$ from every part of that ring due to the symmetry of the problem.